# Conditional rewrite in the regex, not with RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, loops, url-rewriting, conditional-statements

I wrote a regex for a rewrite rule that includes a negative lookahead to replace the rewriteCond line, because WordPress only accepts two values: pattern -> substitution.

It should find findme.html _here, regardless of where it's requested to be:
`mydomain.com/_here/findme.html`
e.g.

(Sorry, I can't modify the swf which will request findme.html in the wrong places)

So, given findme.html could be requested to be in, e.g.:

```
mydomain.com/findme.html
mydomain.com/directory/findme.html
mydomain.com/directory/findme.html?someparam=3
```

The rewrite should make them all

`mydomain.com/_here/findme.html`

So, I made a rewrite rule that Wordpress will accept me as follow

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*(?!_here)/*findme\.html$ /_here/findme.html [R=301,L]
```

So it only matches URLs which doesn't contain "_here" in it, to prevent extra rewriting or a loop.

The problem is IT DOES loop.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to move the `.*` that is before `(?!_here)` to after it because `(?!_here)` is a negative **lookahead**, so it check that the text `_here` does not come after it. What your regular expression is actually checking is whether your url starts with some character sequence that is not followed by `_here`, and `_here` is a character sequence not followed by `_here`. Then your rule becomes

```
RewriteRule ^(?!_here).*/*findme\.html$ /_here/findme.html [R=301,L]
```

Also, it looks like your pattern will exclude paths with subdirectories such as

```
mydomain.com/directory/subdirectory/findme.html
```

If you also want to include those, the pattern should be

```
RewriteRule ^(?!_here)(.*/)*findme\.html$ /_here/findme.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I made it to work with apache rewrite conditions, but you answered my mistakes. Thanks.